# How to clone Azure DevOps repository using VS2019

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I just installed a fresh copy of VS2019 Pro on a new Windows 10 Pro machine.  My issue is that I'm unable to clone repos from Azure Devops.  It creates a local folder and then hangs.  It never does anything after that.

I have done the following to troubleshoot:

1. Installed Git for Windows
2. Verified that my firewall is not blocking anything using a MS tesst page I found via a troubleshooting page.
3. Deleted all cookies from all browser as the troubleshooter suggested.
4. Tried both the old VisualStudio.com and dev.azure.com server URLS when making a connection    via the Team menu.
5. Tried using Git for Windows to clone but get the same results  as in VS2019.

However, I still get nothing but an empty folder.  The Team Explorer tells me it is "Initiating clone..." and the output pane says it's cloning to the local path that I entered but never gets any further.  And there's no other messages that I can find to tell me what's going on.

So I'm not sure if I missed a setup step or if this is related to something in DevOps that wasn't necessary  for the old Visualstudio.com repos.

Would someone please suggest a way I can further troubleshoot this issue, or let me know what I've missed during setup?

Comment: Is that the same problem with cloning other repos(in azure devops) or repos of github? You can try to reinstall vs2019.

Comment: I don't have any GitHub repos.  This issue is on all repos on DevOps.

Comment: You can try to create a new simple repo(i.e only with a readme file) to see if it can be cloned successfully.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long respond but I finally figured it out.  Turned out to be another software program on my machine (a screen reader).  As soon as I turned it off I was able to successfully clone my repos.

Comment: Please post your findings as an answer so it can help others with similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

This issue turned out to be that another software programs on my machine (a screen reader named JAWS 2019) was somehow blocking communication with the DevOps server.  As soon as I turned it off everything DevOps releated began to act normally again - including cloning and creating repos.

Thanks to all who commented.
-Dan